# Custom macOS VoiceOver rotor won't select last text range in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, voiceover

I'm trying to create a custom rotor to select one of a number of ranges in a text view. The API for this is not documented (though public) so I've adapted it from the Apple sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AccessibilityUIExamples/Listings/AccessibilityUIExamples_CustomRotors_TextView_CustomRotorsTextViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012307-AccessibilityUIExamples_CustomRotors_TextView_CustomRotorsTextViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_28).

The purpose of the code is to provide a way to navigate the history of the game text by selecting a previous command, or "move". These are stored as an NSArray of NSRange value objects.

I get the list of ranges, but if I select the last one, the corresponding range in the actual text view will not be selected. The rest of them work as intended. If I switch to another application and then back, then it will suddenly work, at least until I type another command.

Code sample below. Original code in context [here](https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight/blob/minimal-moves-rotor/application/GlkController.m#L3599-L3659). Video illustrating the problem [here](https://youtu.be/cm66RxudATo).

```
- (NSAccessibilityCustomRotorItemResult *)rotor:(NSAccessibilityCustomRotor *)rotor
                      resultForSearchParameters:(NSAccessibilityCustomRotorSearchParameters *)searchParameters {

    NSAccessibilityCustomRotorItemResult *searchResult = nil;
    NSAccessibilityCustomRotorItemResult *currentItemResult = searchParameters.currentItem;
    NSAccessibilityCustomRotorSearchDirection direction = searchParameters.searchDirection;
    NSRange currentRange = currentItemResult.targetRange;

    NSUInteger currentItemIndex;

    GlkTextBufferWindow *largest = [self largestWithMoves];

    if (!largest)
        return nil;

    NSArray *children = largest.moveRanges;

    currentItemIndex = [children indexOfObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:currentRange]];

    if (currentItemIndex == NSNotFound) {
        // Find the start or end element.
        if (direction == NSAccessibilityCustomRotorSearchDirectionNext) {
            currentItemIndex = 0;
        } else if (direction == NSAccessibilityCustomRotorSearchDirectionPrevious) {
            currentItemIndex = children.count - 1;
        }
    } else {
        if (direction == NSAccessibilityCustomRotorSearchDirectionPrevious) {
            if ((NSInteger)currentItemIndex == 0) {
                currentItemIndex = NSNotFound;
            } else {
                currentItemIndex--;
            }
        } else if (direction == NSAccessibilityCustomRotorSearchDirectionNext) {
            if (currentItemIndex == children.count - 1) {
                currentItemIndex = NSNotFound;
            } else {
                currentItemIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentItemIndex == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSValue *targetRangeValue = children[(NSUInteger)currentItemIndex];

    if (targetRangeValue) {
        NSRange textRange = targetRangeValue.rangeValue;
        searchResult = [[NSAccessibilityCustomRotorItemResult alloc] initWithTargetElement: largest.textview];
        searchResult.targetRange = textRange;
        // By adding a custom label, all ranges are reliably listed in the rotor
        NSString *label = [largest.textview.string substringWithRange:textRange];
        searchResult.customLabel = label;
    }

    return searchResult;
}
```

Comment: Tip: If the documentation is missing, check the headers.

Comment: Thanks! That is good advice, but I realise now that mentioning that the API is undocumented is kind of beside the point, firstly because Apple seems to have pretty much given up on documenting its new APIs, and everybody already knows this, and secondly after having worked on this code for a couple of months, I feel I have a reasonable grasp of how this API works. That doesn't help me with this bug, though.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are passing a text range which is out of bounds. For example, here is what I see when I use the command history menu. Notice "x Closed.", which is incorrect. It should be "close mailbox Closed."

[image]

This isn't always happening, either. I *am* able to select the last command from the rotor in some (most?) cases. So I'd look carefully at the ranges and compare ones that work to ones that do not.

Note also the duplicated initial command in the image below, instead of the "walk up to front door" command. So there are a few different bugs in the current implementation which could contribute to the behavior you're seeing.

Thank you for taking the time to support VoiceOver! It's the perfect project for it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. This seems like the kind NSTextView problem that is usually solved by introducing a delay somewhere to give it time to finish laying out the text in some background system thread, though I'm not sure how well this works with the rotor API.

Comment: If you know of steps to reproduce this bug, please let me know. Here or in the [Github repo issues](https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight/issues/26).